# How to integrate Paypal with node js into REST way

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I need to integrate paypal with node js ( first time ). But node js working as REST server with frontend built on mobile ( Android and iOS ). I think purpose of using return url and cancel url for web based frontend not for mobile.

Previously I implemented Stripe payment gateway which have simple system which generate a auth token on mobile and mobile sent this token to Node Js Rest API. So not node js application have buyer auth token and it process the required payment.

But I am very much confused how Paypal achieve same scenario.

UPDATE : I am using paypal official node js package https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK

UPDATE : After more search, I see some steps in payment flow

1. User paypal payment create API into my REST API to get "payment id" and links.
2. Hit on approval_url link which used for fullfill buyer information on paypal site. After completion, Paypal hit automatically described return url in first API, along with payment id and payer id params.
3. In Return API, use payment id and payer id params to paypal payment execute API.

If all above is actual process to generate payment, Then I am assuming that Backend API only needed third Step which API url could be shared with mobile developer in their integration of paypal. 
So Mobile will

1. create payment
2. Fill Buyer information

While Paypal automatically hit return url where backend API will execute payment.

If this is the recommended ( or only ) way to paypal integration with mobile and rest apis ?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of return and cancel url is to notify the client(mobile or web) for potential user action, if user completes payment then via return url and if user cancels payments via cancel Url

You can use rest or nvp PayPal will support both, they have rest endpoints which you can use to complete the transaction.

https://github.com/santhoshlfms/Android_PayPal_EC_NodeJs_Server_Sample (Node server)

https://github.com/santhoshlfms/Android_PayPal_EC_CustomTab_Demo (Mobile Front end)

you can follow these repo to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: I am using PayPal rest sdk, if there are example to achieve using that.

Comment: instead of calling api on your own pass the data to PayPal SDK... i dont have specific example.